# Anistrophic Deriche filter

Tags: filters, computer-vision

I'm currently studying a Deriche filter.
I've managed to create python program for derivative smoothing from this article [1].
As I understand it, Deriche used one $\alpha$ for smoothing in both directions - *X* and *Y*, so this filter seems to me isotrophic.
Is it correct way to use two *alphas* $-$ $\alpha_x$ and $\alpha_y$ to add anistrophy?

Can someone please explain me the relaion between $\alpha$ in Deriche filter and $\sigma$ in Gaussian filter? In [1] i found an equation [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ga92.png), but i do not understand the symbol П. Is it $\pi$?

Thank you.

[1]: Deriche, R. (1990). Fast algorithms for low-level vision. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 12(1), 78–87. doi:10.1109/34.41386

Comment: Welcome to MSE, that definitely does not look like $\pi\approx3.141592\cdots$.

Comment: @xX A C E Xx Thank you. So do i. In the article they took $\alpha$ = 0.14 and $\sigma$ = 10. From these values П = $625/19 ≈ 3.1887755$.